# Make \addcontentsline automatically determine section depth

Tags: table-of-contents

I use the command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section level}{some content}` inside another newly defined command, and would like it to automatically determine the section depth it is placed inside, and use it as `{section_level}`.

Every time I use this newly defined command of mine, `\addcontentsline` should place "TODO Entry" inside the TOC where in the document the command was placed. I'm using my own simplified TODO notes system, as the packages already created for this purpose isn't really suitable for my document.

Comment: Since you're using `\addcontentsline`, you use it as `\addcontentsline{toc}{section level}{some content}` most likely -- you do know the section level already then. What should be stored in `{sec_unit}` (what's that? A macro name?) What is your purpose with `sec_unit`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Tnx for answering. ´{sec_unit}´ is the manuals reference to what you called section_level. I updated the OP question to clarify why I need automatic determining of the level